# Ajax upload of images to cloudinary rails 5 fails without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cloudinary

I am using [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com) on my rails app (backend) with the following `update` with PATCH action on `covers_controller`:

```
  def update
    @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:slug])

    unless @book.nil?
      @cover = @book.cover
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cover.update(cover_params)
        format.json { render json: @cover, message: 'Saved' }
      else
        format.json { render json: @cover.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This was working fine with `$('form#addFrontImage').submit()` which led to normal reload of cover#show page to :update action as the image was saved to cloudinary.

I then decided to replace to .submit() approach with ajax uploads instead, like so:

```
function uploadFrontImage (inputFile) {
  var validated = false

  validated = validateFiles(inputFile)

  if (validated !== true) return

  $('.loader').removeClass('hidden')

  var file = document.getElementById('cover_front_image').files[0]

  var reader = new FileReader()

  reader.readAsDataURL(file)

  reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('#frontUploadPreview')[0].src = reader.result
  }, false)

  var form = $('#addFrontImage')
  var $file = $('#cover_front_image')

  var formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('cover[front_image]', $file[0].files[0])

  $.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'PATCH',
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res)

      var frontImage = new Image()
      frontImage.src = reader.result

      $('div.front span img').replaceWith(frontImage)

      $('.loader').addClass('hidden')
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  })
}
```

Now this code works the first time I upload an image to a given instance of a resource `cover`. But when I re-upload another image to overwrite the previous image on it, the request is simply completed successfully but no image is saved.

What is happening in here? How should I fix it?

Comment: Second time are you receiving the new path response?

Comment: I can fetch a new instance of the form with `update.js.erb` but there seems a different issue at the moment. It's not uploading a _new_image_ to the model even after the page has been refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I want you to change the code like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    ***type: 'POST'***,
```

Comment: ` patch 'cover/:slug', to: 'covers#update', as: :update_cover `

Comment: I recommend you to run 'rake routes'. So you might be sure that there is 'patch covers#update'

Comment: yeah, there is: `update_cover PATCH      /cover/:slug(.:format)                           covers#update`